# How to block access to Facebook for all users in a small business?

Tags: networking, blocking, facebook, web-filtering

A relative of mine has a small accounting office and he decided to block facebook in the network. Ive been looking for a solution for blocking the https site but I had to enter all ip adresses to access filter list, so maybe you know of a software I can install on every pc (3-4  computers)

pcs have windows xp installed and we are considering buying a new router and try to apply access control on https site of facebook, or maybe url filter, or installing a software

Answer (score 1):

I think [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) is the best solution for you. You just need to change your DNS servers to their's and you can set up filtering easily. You can use their [home](http://www.opendns.com/home-solutions/parental-controls/) version which is free or their [business](http://www.opendns.com/business-security/) version.

Comment: what happens when the client changes the dns of their network connection to google dns?

Comment: I thought you were providing internet access from your router. You set the DNS settings there.